# Sorting Time sampling results in GridDB

Tags: plot, time-series, nosql, sampling, griddb

I am using GridDB, as GridDB's characteristics make it ideal for storing log data.
My patient data contains heart_rate and body_temperature , sampled every second or so, stored as a time series data.
i.e. Each row has a TIMESTAMP when the reading was taken.
Sample data looks like:-
[image: Time Series health monitor data]

My query requires low frequency data, only a sampling at ten-minute intervals is required. Then I will use this data to plot a  line chart.

Using The TIME_SAMPLING function I have written my query as:-

`SELECT TIME_SAMPLING(* , TIMESTAMP('2023-07-01T00:00:00Z'), TIMESTAMP('2023-07-07T00:00:00Z'), 10, MINUTE) from My_Data_Table`

Which works well, but I also want the results sorted on body_temperature, to create a tabular representation too.

Any idea how to SORT these results ?